# Interacting like a Mealy machine in sequential VHDL

Tags: vhdl

We're working on testing a circuit that writes to memory, so the test bench needs to read bytes from memory.  However the memory is intended to be read by a Mealy machine. The protocol for the reader is this:

1. It requests a read by setting oReadRequest high and setting the address bus.
2. It waits until the next clock period.
3. If before the end of that next clock period, the request has been acknowledged by iReading being high, then the reader can find the result on the data bus, and has the option of setting oReadRequest to low, or putting a new address on the address bus.
4. If by the end of that next clock period the request has not been acknowledged, the reader keeps the address the same and oReadRequest high and then it's back to step 2.

This is easy enough to implement in concurrent VHDL with a Mealy machine. But for the test benches I'd like to have a procedure that can read a byte, which means using only sequential statements.

Here is what we have. And it works. (At least it works in pre-synthesis testing.)  But it seems wrong somehow to have a wait based on time.  Our clock period is 10ns.  The 3 ns seems completely arbitrary.

```
    procedure readByte(
        signal iReading : in std_ulogic;
        signal iData : in NineBitByte;
        address : in ByteAddress;
        signal oReadRequest : out std_ulogic;
        signal oReadAddress : out ByteAddress;
        result : out NineBitByte) is 
    begin

        loop
            -- Request a byte.
            oReadAddress <= address; 
            oReadRequest <= '1';

            wait until rising_edge( clock );

            -- Wait for a little while
            -- to give the memory arbiter time to react
            -- to the request.
            wait for 3 ns;

            -- Is it acknowledged?
            exit when iReading = '1';
        end loop;

        result := iData;
        -- Tentatively reset the request line.
        -- A subsequent read in this cycle might
        -- overturn this assignment.
        oReadRequest <= '0';
    end procedure;
```

We are using VHDL-93 in case that makes a difference.

So the specific question is whether there is a way to write the procedure without putting in arbitrary time delays.

The more general question is whether there is a way to write sequential VHDL to emulate a Mealy machine without knowing how fast the other process will react.  With concurrent assignments, an input such as `iReading` that might change partway trough a clock cycle can be continuously monitored and changes reacted to at any time in the clock cycle. In the code I have above, I picked a specific time in each clock cycle to observe this input.

Comment: You haven't provided a specific programming question. You're also asking your reading audience to peer through a keyhole only providing a snippet. As a guess the delay relates to an anticipated post synthesis timed model. Your readers have no insight into the arbiter. Depending on duty cycle and clock period you might  be able to use the clock falling edge instead of a specific delay.

Comment: To access data written to the memory, an alternative is to make a test-only (simulation) port, where the test bench can access any memory location immediately, by having the full memory array as a signal, or a combinatorial read address input and data outputs.  Such a port should be excluded from synthesis, thus won't have any effect on the actual implementation.

Comment: There is nothing named `iReadRequest` or `sReadRequest` in the VHDL code you show.

Comment: I do not understand _It waits until the next clock period_. You can wait **for** a **duration** or **until** an **event** but what do you mean by waiting **until** a **time interval**? Does it mean wait until the second next rising edge of the clock? If yes why don't you simply `wait until rising_edge(clock)` twice?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet  Thx.  The `iReadRequest` and `sReadRequest` should both have been oReadRequest.  Fixed.  "It waits until the next clock period" I meant it waits until the start of the next clock period; i.e., waits until the next rising edge of the clock.  If the second `for 3 ns` were replaced by `until rising_edge( clock )` that would not work because, if `iReadingByte` is high at that edge, it will then be too late for the reader to change the address if it needs to read another byte, and if it doesn't need to read again, it would be too late to lower the oReadRequest.

Comment: @user16145658 .  You are right that this is a specific example, but really I'm interested in the broader question of whether there is a sensible way to use sequential code to emulate a Mealy machine.  I tried to explain the other agent, although I made a couple of mistakes doing that, which I have corrected.  The 3 ns delay needs to be there, even for pre-sythesis testing, although the number could be anything greater than 0 and less than 10.  I think what's missing from my explanation of the arbiter is that I didn't specify how quickly it reacts in real time.

Comment: @user16145658 Continuing the last comment. If that's the case, that I needed to have specified how soon after a rising clock edge the arbiter sets the iReadingByte and iData lines rather than just saying "sometime before the next clock edge", then that pretty much answers my question.

Comment: @MortenZilmer Thanks.  That sounds like a good approach for this particular example.  It doesn't really answer my more general question (which I don't think I articulated well) of whether I can get sequential code to act like a Mealy machine without putting in specific but mostly arbitrary time delays.  I've edited the question a bit to try to make the question clearer.

Comment: I still dont fully understand the question, even after your clarification comments. All VHDL code is sequential, but various mechanics may make it appear not so. For example, order of signal assignments makes a difference, as "last one wins". Are you asking if it can be modelled using a `procedure`?  IMO, a procedure that waits an arbitrary time to read a bus is either put there to model a specific requirement, or is a "fudge" to make it work. Your spec requires `iReading` being high on a clock edge, but this does not happen in your own code.

Comment: @Tricky My spec said "3. If *by* the end of that next clock period, the request has been acknowledged by iReading"  I should have said "before" rather than "by".  You are right about the problem with my code. It only waits 3ns rather than waiting until just before the next rising clock edge.   This would be a problem if the other agent were slow about lowering its acknowledgement of the previous byte.  That's one of the reasons that I'm not happy with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Reading again your specifications and your code I think that we could reformulate as "*assert `oReadRequest` high, wait until the next rising edge of the clock, and then, if `iReading` is not already asserted high, wait until it is*".

The second wait can last 0 time if `iReading` is already asserted high, or less than one clock period if it is asserted high before the next rising edge of the clock or more, it does not make any difference, the behaviour is the same: just stop waiting when `iReading` is asserted high.

So, if I am right, you could replace the body of your procedure by:

```
begin
    -- Request a byte.
    oReadAddress <= address; 
    oReadRequest <= '1';
    -- wait next rising edge of clock
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    -- if not acknowledged
    if iReading /= '1' then
        -- wait until acknowledge
        wait until iReading = '1';
    end if;

    result := iData;
    oReadRequest <= '0';
end procedure;
```

In case you know for sure that `iReading` will be 0 after the first rising edge of the clock, we can reformulate as "*assert `oReadRequest` high, wait until the next rising edge of the clock, and then, wait until `iReading` is asserted high*":

```
begin
    -- Request a byte.
    oReadAddress <= address; 
    oReadRequest <= '1';
    -- wait next rising edge of clock
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    -- wait until acknowledge
    wait until iReading = '1';

    result := iData;
    oReadRequest <= '0';
end procedure;
```

In both cases, when returning from your procedure call, you can call it again with a different address and this will chain consecutive requests without delay.

Finally, if none of these interpretations is correct I think you are facing another kind of issue: after having sent your request you don't know what to wait for, that signals its acknowledgement. And this is not a VHDL problem, it is a specification problem.

Comment: And if you acknowledge ambiguity in a question, see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) **Answer [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions** "Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... • ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem. ..." (A clear and complete question would make correct answers possible, otherwise it's guessing and certainly not verifiable.)

Comment: Thanks.  This answer got me thinking in what I think is the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It got me thinking in the direction a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering my own question.]

The key idea that I was missing is that it is possible to wait on more than one signal.  A Mealy machine needs to react not only to the clock edge, but also to other signals.  Usually this is handled using concurrency, with different processes waiting on different signals. To handle it without concurrency requires one process to wait on multiple signals.

In the particular example that I had, it gets a bit complicated, especially if I try to encapsulate the behaviour in a procedure. I found I had to write two procedures, one for bytes that are not read immediately after another has been read, and one for bytes that are to be read immediately after another has been read.  The behaviour of the procedures now depends on whether another byte (after the one that the procedure obtains) needs to be read as soon as possible or not, so I had to add two more parameters `moreToRead` and `nextAddress`. The key line is `wait on iReading, clock` in the second procedure.

```
-- Example usage: To read 3 bytes in a row.
--   readFirstByte( iReading, iData, addr, '1', addr+1,
--                  oReadRequest, oReadAddress, byte0 ) ;
--   readSubsequentByte( iReading, iData, addr+1, '1', addr+2,
--                  oReadRequest, oReadAddress, byte1 ) ;
--   readSubsequentByte( sReading, sData, addr+2, '0', anything,
--                  oReadRequest, oReadAddress, byte2 ) ;
procedure readFirstByte(
    signal iReading : in std_ulogic;
    signal iData : in NineBitByte;
    address : in ByteAddress;
    moreToRead : in std_ulogic ;
    nextAddress : in ByteAddress;
    signal oReadRequest : out std_ulogic;
    signal oReadAddress : out ByteAddress;
    result : out NineBitByte)
is 
begin
    -- Request a byte.
    oReadRequest <= '1';
    oReadAddress <= address; 
    wait until rising_edge( clock );
    readSubsequenByte( iReading, iData, address moreToRead, nextAddress, oRequestRead, oReadAddress, result ) ;
end ;

procedure readSubsequentByte(
    signal iReading : in std_ulogic;
    signal iData : in NineBitByte;
    address : in ByteAddress;
    moreToRead : in std_ulogic ;
    nextAddress : in ByteAddress;
    signal oReadRequest : out std_ulogic;
    signal oReadAddress : out ByteAddress;
    result : out NineBitByte)
is 

    -- Precondition: 
    --   oReadRequest = '1' and oAddress = address
    --  was true at the previous clock edge. 

    -- Postcondition: rising_edge(clock)
    -- and result = iData 
    -- and (iReading = '1' is true and has been true for some
    --     time before this clock edge) 
    --     (oReadRequest = moreToRead and oAddress =  nextAddress
    --      is true and was true at the previous clock edge)

    variable readComplete : boolean ;
begin
    loop
        if iReading then  
            --Tentatively assume the read is complete
            readComplete := true ;
            --Tentatively request the next byte if one is needed.
            oReadRequest <= moreToRead ;
            oReadAdress <= nextAddress ; 
        else  
            --Tentatively assume the read is not complete
            readComplete := false ;
            --Tentatively request the same byte.
            oReadRequest <= '1' ;
            oReadAddress <= address ;
        end if
        wait on iReading, clock ;
        exit when rising_edge( clock ) and readComplete and iReading = '1' ;
    end loop ;
    result := iData ;
end ;
```

Now, if the `iReading` input changes in the middle of a clock cycle, the reading process reacts to that by changing its outputs immediately.